# How do I make the parts layer smaller in a Fritzing part?

Tags: fritzing

I am using Fritzing to create a schematic of a recent project. I am using several 'parts' from the parts bins. I had to go find a part to add, and I have imported it.

I got the part here:
[SMD based 4 x Relay Board](http://fritzing.org/projects/smd-4-x-relay-board)

It is exactly what I need. I have imported it into "Mine" parts bin. But The "parts layer" of this item far exceeds the size of the part. So it makes a big gray area that covers other parts and doesn't look good.

**Question: How do I make this parts layer / gray area smaller?**

(Note: The attached screenshot shows this. I have added notes onto the screenshot to show exactly what I am describing, and what I am desiring to do.)

Context:

- I could probably just change the order and put it on bottom, but I still want to understand for the future how to make things like this smaller
- I have tried editing the part, etc. but nothign gets me to the point where I can re-size this gray area.

Thank you.

[image: Diagram of my schematic]

Under the view menu are layers. If I deselect the parts layer, the gray disappears (along with much of the graphic.) This seems to indicate that it's the "parts layer" which is too big. It seems I might need to figure out how to make that layer smaller. I have tried clicking, editing, looking for 'handles' I could click and drag to resize, etc. without success yet.

[image: Layers menu]

Comment: Not an answer, but my advice is to abandon fritzing and use a proper schematic capture tool.

Comment: What do you recommend, Elliot?

Comment: @JackAmoratis, ask for software suggestion at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [KiCAD.](https://kicad.org/) [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: EAGLE..........

Comment: If you don't want to pay for an arm and a leg, definitely KiCAD since that is open source and quite good actually. EAGLE and Altium Allegro and yada yada are usually for commercial use.